# Django deployed app shows "It worked!", instead of app (Gunicorn + Nginx)

Tags: django, gunicorn

Morning all - I've got an issue I didn't encounter with previous Django apps I've deployed. I have a working application that only uses the admin app and a custom management command for automated email reminders.

This app worked fine on my development machine, with a working admin interface and working custom management command. I copied the entire project directory from the dev machine to the server, and all I get is the generic "It worked!" page I'd expect from a brand new project.

I find this rather odd, as the project was copied verbatim from a working installation to a location with the exact path name. Anyone have an idea?

Edit: As noted in comments below, I found the issue to be the compiled .pyc files I had copied over along with my project code. I don't know enough about Python to understand why the .pyc files would not be portable. Deleting all .pyc files prior to copying over the project, and then running `syncdb` solved the issue.

Comment: Also, I have cleared browser cache to no avail.

Comment: Did the urls.py file get copied? The cause of the welcome is normally no urls defined.

Comment: Thanks for the post, Kekoa - note my comments to the answer below: turns out the .pyc files from my other machine were interfering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a url map for the `^$` pattern (which is basically an empty URL). This is what is loaded when you simply type the URL without a path component.

`example.com` = `^$`

`example.com/` = `^/$`, although the [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) setting helps with this (its on by default).

If you turn off `DEBUG` - which you should do in production - you will no longer see that page. Make you have to provide a `404.html` and `500.html` template for the respective error conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the post, burhan. I'd answer my own question, but I don't have enough rep yet. The issue were the compiled .pyc files I copied along with my project. They were somehow interfering.

Comment: Also, one of the things that tipped me off is that setting DEBUG = False was still showing the "It worked!" page. Turns out gunicorn was serving the compiled python files (as it should do, for speed's sake) instead of running the actual .py files. 

./manage.py syncdb wasn't doing anything because the .pyc files already existed, too. So moral of the story - delete .pyc files if copying a project to the production server from dev! :)

Comment: Marked your answer as good, since it could help someone without the .pyc files issue.

Comment: To force regeneration of `.pyc`, simply change the `mtime` of the file - which you can do with `touch` (in addition to, as you noted, simply deleting the `.pyc` file will also do the trick).

Comment: Hey, that's handy to know. Thanks burhan!

Comment: Using a source revision control system like git or svn is a good idea in general, but especially for this reason. Just add *.pyc to the ignore list, and when you pull down in production you always have a pristince copy.